# SharePoint not reflecting CSS Changes

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, css, master-page

I am trying to make a css change to my sharepoint 2013 site. I make the change to the css and save it, but it isn't reflected on the site.

Things I have tried:

- I make a more drastic broadly scoped change to the css, something
  like div{border: 2px solid red} and it still doesn't show up
- Deleted CSS file -> css still being applied to site normally
- Restored css file and changed the name in file explorer view -> Sharepoint updates my Masterpage.html link tag automatically and css changes are now reflected correctly. Tried to make a new change in newly renamed file. Change NOT represented on site. Rename to a 3rd name -> site reflects changes correctly.
- Changed link tag in masterpage.html manually back to 1st name of css file -> site's styling changes back to styles inline with old css before any changes even tho there is NO file in the directory with this name.
- Changes link tag to name of 2nd rename of css file -> Site changes in line with css during that rename state. This file ALSO does not exist currently
- Empty all caches, files, temps. Try different browsers, Try incognito mode. Everything continues to be inline with previous findings.
- Inspecting css file in developer tools displays css file inline with the stat at whichever naming I check. So If the link tag is pointing to the non-existent first name of css it will open a css file with no changes even tho that file does not exist.

What am I missing? Is sharepoint copying these files somewhere and then somehow accessing them even those the href is pointing to a location that doesn't exist?

Answer (score 2):

**Try to do the following:**

1. Clear your IE Browser Cache,

   - Open IE, hold `Ctrl + F5`,
   - Then hold `Ctrl+Shift+Del` to delete the selected below

[image]

2. Edit your CSS file via SharePoint Designer

   - Open SharePoint Designer, Open your site.
   - Navigate to all files > Check out your file, Open your CSS file in advanced mode.
   - Edit your CSS file and make sure that you are using `!important` like this

     ```
     div{border: 2px solid red !important;}
     ```
   - Save your changes, Check in your file.if it requires Publish publish it as a major version.
   - Browse your site now it should be reflected with your CSS changes.

Comment: Didn't work. Same behavior as above. New Css Change not reflected. Sharepoint still able to show css from file that no longer exists and infact can display and download entire deleted css file if referenced via old name.

Comment: do you enable publishing feature?

Comment: This folder, the "assets" folder in the _catalogs/masterpage doesn't require or allow publishing. I can check out and check in but there's no option to publish. Also I should note that this all worked as of a couple weeks ago when I have to make the last css change it was as simple as just editing the .css file and saving.

Comment: do you added !important

Comment: yeah I copied exactly what you put in your post. Also it's easy to see if the change is being picked up in dev tools since the old version of the file was compressed css and to make it obvious the new version is uncompressed css. It is still showing the old compressed version. Which doesn't even exist anymore since I deleted it and emptied sharepoint's recycling bin

Comment: Okay, try to add another style like a link tag this and check if reflecting or not a:link {
    color: red !important;
}

Comment: No Change, same Results as above. Still showing the compressed original CSS from before the first rename if I point the Link tag at that name and the version at the moment of the rename if I point it at one of the renamed names.

Comment: Not sure if it helps, but I remember in SP2010 one had to use `After="corev4.css"` in the reference path to your css in the master page to overwrite the standard SP CSS. `SharePoint:CssRegistration name="/style library/yourCSS" After="corev15.css" runat="server"/`. Apart from a browser cache, I think it's impossible that SP refers to file that doesn't exist anymore. If Dev Tools still refers to that css file name, hover over it to see the reference path of the location of the file.

Comment: Looking in devtools at the css file it says it's in my assets/css folder which when I open and look at in every way I can look at it (explorer as a virtual directory, in sharepoint gui itself, in a browser) does not contain this file.

Comment: Did anyone find the solution to this problem, I am experiencing exactly same thing, everything here has been done with no change.  @Neberu did you find a solution to this problem?